# Typescript flow analysis not working for dictionary of functions whose type depends on the key

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript 4.6

In my project I have a type called `FooterFormElement` which has a discriminant property `type`

```js
type FooterFormElement = {type:"number",...}|{type:"button",...};
```

To instantiate these elements I have a dictionary called `footerFormElementDictionary`:

```js
footerFormElementDictionary:{
    [key in FooterFormElement["type"]]: (element: FooterFormElement & { type: key }) => HTMLElement
}
```

The problem is, when I try to use this dictionary, like in the following example

```js
this.footerFormElementDictionary[item.type](item)
```

I get the error: `Argument of type 'FooterFormElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'`
It seems as if the typescript compiler can't "unroll" the flow analysis for the different values of `type`.

Any way I can fix this (apart from ugly non-type-safe workarounds).

Here is a shortened minimal reproduceable example:

```js
type FooterFormData = { [k: string]: number };

type FooterFormElement = {
  type: "button"; Action: (data: FooterFormData) => void;
} | {
  type: "number"; label: string; Action?: (value: number) => void;
}

declare const footerFormElementDictionary: {
  [K in FooterFormElement["type"]]: (
    element: FooterFormElement & { type: K },
    formData: FooterFormData
  ) => HTMLElement;
}

function MakeFooterForm(elements: FooterFormElement[]): HTMLElement[] {
  let formData: FooterFormData = {};
  return elements.map((item) =>
    footerFormElementDictionary[item.type](item, formData)
  );
}
```

Here is a [reproduceable example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgXALAlgZ0gMwK4DsDGtED2WkOATgKYCGs5qlx8sAtgDaTkvlPlawA0kAFYZksSJUjJ4BUgnoATKCGDhMufEUhNKAa3IBRTt14AeANLsAHjSzzUegJ4E0kABIAVALIAZQ1x6w7pQA5gBylNyelAAOAHwAFFDsRgEAXJBmfEk4LJTIyLTpoqSIWMFZkJCMrAD8RbAlZRXisA3IdZAA3pAA2o71jcEAugOlwZAAvuAAlF1JnGIcXJAAvJDyBDgYxrAAdGRUNH478Us70wDcSWf7ufnh3KskdwXIV0mILvHVLLOdSZUbqUsORSB4fE8fldKlNKp9IPFqG0-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-L5KrDw4VrdHa-xeESNcsyWlhrLPXqaslCamqmmhrD2tcAANfW0FgWFiAASToYp2iYTGAGa2Xuy7UXm3kqr6yUVuMjr9sB2ALrTLN1IGqDeEatgYbhhoCBYabZt43lsHkcg0FKch5ExyoKr5CjNzA3czyXSpkrhL4Yu0SwUTXcHdkZp4PMgABqLyAjZ39F1ReFThYtnSmZtNWeA4g1k5nmGdKQW+VZohwYiqK1yqm87yeVntfIYVkFCCnv0Su0ehi9shiefXv2FmK4qIWYHbQrBrzZO9acmNLeXBhqTt2GIDVseIdoEcGvYyjUxvqyacvAVLwFUbBXcgKI9BrJirRF9bYGQYTCNjEyeg5dIpOL63sKqs3GwLrONMbOTE8qYBgAQFA8NQBBDWiRqMSMahUMq-GklbqCceD9YCFoLAAHIxAKZZFJIZ1DVzZ9kHH8gVV0zLed4ZB+eiOkxy4ZtUQpQvmNzlDXYwnpT6YXYKKGeJH+KsTG2mCTtST6uELrvBK0Fcng9CSBVMmkBzJ5ispjR2ZYSDQVRuQXYLACDlFRL5Xs5F4BrwsvmJIuViaokgVmfKkMDyUCPNmbukByGY3bNmDEWZCHgCGO8cAcNkDINQegsyGJTRoDmlcDYWxvLBF0iZAAQg4AAkvIMyNBRBzRqIHaIwcFG7C0encgmcgFMASghaYyUk5AA) showcasing the problem.

Comment: Playground if possible demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/NBjvkN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: @jcalz I attached some examples

Comment: I don't see any destructuring going on in any of this code; can you point to it?  Either I'm missing it or "destructured flow analysis" isn't relevant here.  Either way, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w66Yvw) meet your needs? The problem is that TS doesn't see the correlation between the type of `footerFormElementDictionary[item.type]` and type of `item`; they are both just unions and treated independently. This is [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). TS4.6 *does* have a solution for this, but it requires some refactoring of types.

Comment: If that approach works for you and you want me to write up an answer, could you please first [edit] the question so that the necessary [mre] is also present as plain text in the post?  People shouldn't be required to follow an external link to see the issue (although having the link is a nice supplement).  And also, if it turns out that you are not using destructuring at all, please edit the title and body of the question to describe what you're actually doing.  Let me know!

Comment: @jcalz 1. your approach does meet my needs, thanks. 

2. I changed my post to be more accurate, though I don't want to put all of my code in the post as I feel like that would make the post quite bloated. it's around 100 lines of code.

3. also, I was actually referring to your corelated union types post, was just a misunderstanding on my end.

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: You don't have to put 100 lines of code in the question.  [This version](https://tsplay.dev/WJ426N) reproduces your problem with only about 20 lines.  Could you [edit] that into your question so I can target it with my answer?

Comment: @jcalz I will, didn't really think of reproducing the error without the functionality, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For concreteness and brevity I will specify your types slightly differently from in your external links:

```
type FooterFormElement =
  { type: "button"; buttonStuff: string } |
  { type: "number"; numberStuff: string };

declare const footerFormElementDictionary: {
  [K in FooterFormElement["type"]]: (
    element: Extract<FooterFormElement, { type: K }>
  ) => HTMLElement;
}
```

It seems like you should be able to grab any `item` of type `FooterFormElement`, and call `footerFormElementDictionary[item.type](item)`.   But, as you saw, the compiler is unable to verify that this is type safe:

```
function problem(item: FooterFormElement) {
  const fn = footerFormElementDictionary[item.type];
  return fn(item); // error!
  // -----> ~~~~
  // Argument of type 'FooterFormElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  // The intersection '{ type: "number"; numberStuff: string; } & 
  // { type: "button"; buttonStuff: string; }'  // was reduced to 'never'
}
```

Let's use IntelliSense to see what types the compiler sees for `fn` and `item`:

```
/* const fn: (
(element: { type: "number"; numberStuff: string }, 
 formData: FooterFormData) => HTMLElement
) | (
(element: { type: "button"; buttonStuff: string }, 
 formData: FooterFormData) => HTMLElement
) */

/* (parameter) item: 
{ type: "button"; buttonStuff: string; } | 
{ type: "number"; numberStuff: string; } */
```

The type of `fn` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of function types, and the type of `item` is also a union.  These types are not *wrong*, but they are not useful enough for your purposes.  The compiler treats these unions as *uncorrelated*.  The compiler only knows that `fn` is *either* something that accepts a `"button"`-like input, *or* something that types a `"number"`-like input, but it doesn't know which.

And so the only input it could safely accept would be something which is *both* `"button"`- *and* `"number"`-like.  Which would be the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the input types.  And since the input types are members of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions), the intersection of two incompatible members is reduced to [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).

Again, the compiler is concerned that maybe `fn` will accept a `"number"`-like input but `item` will turn out to be `"button"`-like, or vice versa.  This cannot happen because `fn` is correlated to `item`, but that correlation is not represented in the types of `fn` and `item`. This problem, where the compiler cannot verify that two union types are correlated, is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

Before TypeScript 4.6 I would have told you to just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to suppress the error, or to write some redundant code if you really care about type safety more than convenience.  There wasn't anything better.

---

TypeScript 4.6 introduced some [indexed access improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which allow us to refactor the code to represent `FooterFormElement` and `footerFormElementDictionary` in terms of *distributive object types*, so that the problematic function call can succeed as a *generic* function.

Here's the refactoring.  First we take the original `FooterFormElement` and refactored it to a key-value mapping type where the original `type` property is now a key and the rest of the properties are the new value type:

```
interface FooterFormElementMap {
  button: { buttonStuff: string },
  number: { numberStuff: string }
}
```

Then we can write `FooterFormElement` as a *distributive object type*, which is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union of all the property types:

```
type FooterFormElement<K extends keyof FooterFormElementMap =
  keyof FooterFormElementMap> =
  { [P in K]: { type: P } & FooterFormElementMap[P] }[K];
```

If you just write `FooterFormElement` you get something equivalent to the same union type as before:

```
type Test = FooterFormElement;
/* type Test = 
    ({ type: "number"; } & { numberStuff: string; }) | 
    ({ type: "button"; } & { buttonStuff: string; }) */
```

And if you write `FooterFormElement<"button">` or `FooterFormElement<"number">` you will get just the member of the union you care about.  This lets us write `FooterFormElement<K>` as a generic type.

Finally, we rewrite the type of `footerFormElementDictionary` in terms of `FooterFormElement<K>` for each `K` in the keys of `FooterFormElementMap`:

```
declare const footerFormElementDictionary: {
  [K in keyof FooterFormElementMap]: (
    element: FooterFormElement<K>
  ) => HTMLElement;
}
```

This representation turns out to be important, and is what allows the compiler to see the relationship between properties in `footerFormElementDictionary` and values of type `FooterFormElement` for generic `K`.

And finally we can turn the problematic function from before into a generic working version:

```
function solution<K extends keyof FooterFormElementMap>(item: FooterFormElement<K>) {
  const fn: (element: FooterFormElement<K>) => HTMLElement =
    footerFormElementDictionary[item.type];
  // item: FooterFormElement<K>
  return fn(item) // okay!
}
```

This works because `fn` is seen as a function which takes a `FooterFormElement<K>` and `item` is seen as a `FooterFormElement<K>`.  So if you have an array of `FooterFormElement`, you can use `map()` with a generic callback and it'll just work:

```
function MakeFooterForm(elements: FooterFormElement[]): HTMLElement[] {
  return elements.map(<K extends keyof FooterFormElementMap>(
    item: FooterFormElement<K>) => footerFormElementDictionary[item.type](item) // 
  );
}
```

Hooray!

---

Just to be painfully clear, if we rewrite `footerFormElementDictionary`'s type annotation as a structurally equivalent version that does not mention `FooterFormElement<K>`, this will all break:

```
declare const badDictionary: {
  button: (element: { type: "button"; } & { buttonStuff: string; }) => HTMLElement;
  number: (element: { type: "number"; } & { numberStuff: string; }) => HTMLElement;
}

function problemAgain<K extends keyof FooterFormElementMap>(item: FooterFormElement<K>) {
  return badDictionary[item.type](item); // error!
  // ---------------------------> ~~~~
  // Argument is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
}
```

As you can see, the correlation between the function and the argument types is fragile, and depends on a connection between their type definitions.  So be careful.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkqJLAsgPIBOAlgOZ6HHEAuAnjMgGID2vrCNT7UwAUQwRIwVkgC8RFsVxIOXAFxIARACMArq1a9gWgNxJ9h4wGVWegGb3NUVnWCMAvkgA+ipSrUITS1gPTAdITMSMIjqWwcnJBc3T1NmFgATCHgMEGpkeGMXJHt+QWFeUQkpCBkAEVp4VlpjPPZNAiViAG0AaSRaYCQ+ASERcUlpVm6tQK0AXXnNAAo-LohJ2tZNMQAPVwRWAB4R8vHqqYAaPFVOIKR+jwA+NeIASnknpAAJABUAWQAMhctmklB50sR7HpgE0WkMYNReDpJstaIIwJpTmNKhMajIPp0uoVgMV7EM5CUyjiqpt6o1mq1qOxuuipAA6QLzMFdAD0ACokCSycAVq8WMsNvjtjdAsFQuFIuYFbF4o5nK5Bp5ruKWKVRHUQKwQFjqRUDUaQB85F8-kCQTJdUgPt4kKsuhKpVMOrcNNpLEYTOYAzY7Oqkpr3EgPDqPXrcYbjabRuawImrZ8fgDgXTWE6PvzeZCWAK3XBqOAIOUPmzMUgnbK7sEQ0GLAZA2rEskteYvK6GwEm9oVUrooq4mGu5H6L2kIXi8R8nZqENyWiMW9zLzeUghEjqABCcXbpAAWnP56+AD8b1fjzuAILUehhLZIXj2X3IADk2NTDtYb8BigEgBCQEAoCgBhQBRZAjCQctK3Kd9P0CJBv2ACAADchG-dl7yQX4AAtkEGcooGyRkhm-Qc-RCGJRxHCcEg1FJZwAMnrD0T1o+5dHbYwohbTtWJ7aMgKQE8AHcIKQfIMj0RAMlUXh0MwnDqG-NYIWICFCEUUhoDgRBhloXYmDWMihHsChhjNc5c3+EAYCYD0Wx9YTJ1EqMY3FJifSYkSIxSaNtOLNC-wc6Ujn6CB9lqDIQIAawgdgPzslMoqmJyXIUD0UrSz9ItxACcq+PKuhUboAAUBiGXolkbP1aq8TjitpaUcpq+Zoz6blwruQjoFkSl2rxKYeWIUs0N+Yb5C4uNll4+UGOoKJWpuQKvOCsSPBdBaPSWr9mwE1sNpUTyWJ29xewLIs1iyHI8gKIpZFKTKStzBo4SZdpXK6Po6qQAr0rG0rnMa904y9LZkzOT7ot6F4PWtW1swAybQuLaFYSopJeAwAx4Ri3d4uARLgdS0H7IR7LnKedcpDhmlxq2GKnkJcVhTe0U3RhmRmf-XN2dRrN7VzeQnXe+GOqmb6qLaVkMU5O5+u4nda0FrK2aR8Ulz0FcSmARmwE3SSd14JKQHYI9wWLR7cnyIVXosEAMnl+E2g6cV3L53MfTlf1TvWpBOIu06gu7G7o1Fu0c2lTHiH8v3pQDod6PHEOw7HVVtqjmcY8zOOMbCpQcZ+hEkVgsAH3oEBBhJuLBHJ5KqaKmnZa2MqTa12mdY5-6lH1w2dDdj3fqVjkuRNs2Tz3Spbb5HcLxX1e1-Xy8kFvO91aQJ8XymYDQNkCCoPoGDJBUhC8iQoQUK-NTsNwsLsZhCukCclKxslXMoF7zuZDdHmG8TQxdcxAMHiwYeQx+asCgOyMAzlliNzJhTEG7cPoANYN3J0msMoy1ZjIEWmZpYswAuPUAzJJ5gBVlweYM9xSbhfukPSHggA)

Comment: thanks for the solution, I do have one small inconvenience, some of my element types share some properties, for example, the "number" and "money" types share almost all of their properties, is their any way to do that with the interface without repeating the properties?

Comment: So that problem is a followup question, right?  I don't see how this solution could have created that problem so presumably it was already present, and is therefore not really in scope here.  Without knowing more I'd say you should create interfaces for the common properties and then either extend or intersect them with the nonshared properties.